# Apache Send .java files as text instead of download

Tags: apache-2.2, html, text, configuration

How do I configure my apache instance to simply load *.java files in browser instead of sending it to me as a download?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put this somewhere convenient:

```
AddType text/plain .java
```

in your httpd.conf file. You can find this file via:

```
$ /usr/sbin/apachectl -V | egrep "(HTTPD_ROOT|SERVER_CONFIG_FILE)"
-D HTTPD_ROOT="/etc/httpd"
-D SERVER_CONFIG_FILE="conf/httpd.conf"
```

(the typical location is `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf`)

then restart your apache with

```
/usr/sbin/apachectl graceful
```

Comment: Thanks, is there also a way to set this as the default for all "unknown files"?

Comment: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#defaulttype